# Why is my Bootstrap fixed top navbar so small on mobile?

Tags: navbar

Context: http://tomtam.net

Example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

My navbar is tiny mobile. Also how can I center the image ? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean 'so small' ? On my Win 10 Phone everything looks as expected... Can you provide any example, maybe printscreen ?

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap Navbar Screenshot https://imgur.com/tkLZpeH

Comment: Ok, I see... Look like browser related issue or problem with your html... Like I said on MS Edge on Win10 Phone it's look good - expect issue with right margin/padding, but this is for all page not only navbar.

Comment: Check this: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ftomtam.net%2F (especially section 4 and 5)

Comment: About centring image - if you ask about image on your printscreen - then its related to html (or margin/padding) issue in your code... But can't tell exactly, because there is no image on given link ;) If this is about another image then try bootstrap class 'text-center' or 'center-block' or just use CSS style 'align: center'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Place it before `<title>` tag.

---

Also, you should place your "row" div inside a div with "container" class.

Comment: SOLVED - Bootstrap Navbar Fixed-top Screenshot https://imgur.com/Z1ilahk